# Graph a line in matplotlib based on the comparison of 2 pandas columns

Tags: pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

This should be a simple question, but hours of searching and reading the docs has not helped find an answer to this simple, yet age-old pandas "how to do something if the value in one column is < the value in another column.

I am seriously struggling with the syntax and nomenclature that pandas uses. It is not at all intuitive to me to the point where I can't even ask the right question or apply useful tags when searching.

My project is to graph a series of time cycles so I can visually see when in the calendar year the cycles start and end and if they spill over to another calendar year as per the following sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {'Period':['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'], 'Start':[338,78,190,273], 'End':[117,166,299,17]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#print (df) # for testing

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.xlim([-5,370])   # set x-axis limits to be number of days in calendar year with spacer of 5 days on either side for ease of viewing

ax.scatter(df['Start'],df['Period'],color = 'green', label = 'Cycle Start', marker = '|', s = 100, zorder = 2)  # plot 
ax.scatter(df['End'],df['Period'],color = 'red', label = 'Cycle End', marker = '|', s = 100, zorder = 2)

ax.vlines(0,-1,len(df['Period']),color='purple', label = 'Calendar Year Start / End',linewidth = 2, zorder = 1)   # put vertical line at Day 0 of calendar year
ax.vlines(365,-1,len(df['Period']),color='purple', linewidth = 2, zorder = 1) # put vertical line at Day 365 of calendar year


##
#   Need to execute one of the following code to draw horizontal line(s) for each period / row in dataframe, not both.
##

##  Option 1: Draw line between start and end points if start and end dates are in same calendar year (green marker to left of red).
ax.hlines(df['Period'], xmin=df['Start'], xmax=df['End'], color='blue', label = 'Cycle', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0) 

##  Option 2: Draw 2 lines if the start or end dates are not in the same calendar year (red marker to left of green).
ax.hlines(df['Period'], xmin=df['Start'], xmax=365, color='orange', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)  # end date is in next calendar year
ax.hlines(df['Period'], xmin=0, xmax=df['End'], color='orange', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)  # start date is in previous calendar year


ax.legend(ncol=2, loc = 'upper center')

## set the x axis to show the month names instead of day numbers
plt.xticks(np.linspace(0,365,13)[:-1], ('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov', 'Dec'))

plt.show()
```

What I can not figure out how to do is the simple pandas conditional magic required to do the following;

```
if df['Start'] < df['End']:
    'draw one line as shown above'
else:
    'draw 2 lines as shown above'
```

What is the pandas syntax to do something based on the value of one column being compared to the value of another column in the same row?

Do I need to use a for loop and draw each line separately, or can this be done through some form of df.loc[df[... or other pandas-style comparison statement?

This should be simple, but I can't see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution that works (not perfectly, but I will take the miracles when they happen).

Used a for loop and went line by line to draw the correct line.

Only problem is that it adds the 'Cycle' Label to the legend every time it draws a blue line (start and end in same calendar year), so I have to remove that label from the hline and add a separate legend entry to retain any sense of readability for datasets with  multiple years of data. And it doesn't necessarily put the label where I want it in the legend (wanted it placed last, so the Cycle Start and Cycle End are in the same column.

Feel free to provide input on that one.

Here's the full code that accomplished what I want to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {'Period':['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'], 'Start':[338,78,190,273], 'End':[117,166,299,17]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#print (df) # for testing

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.xlim([-5,370])   # set x-axis limits to be number of days in calendar year with spacer of 5 days on either side for ease of viewing

ax.scatter(df['Start'],df['Period'],color = 'green', label = 'Cycle Start', marker = '|', s = 100, zorder = 2)  # plot 
ax.scatter(df['End'],df['Period'],color = 'red', label = 'Cycle End', marker = '|', s = 100, zorder = 2)

ax.vlines(0,-1,len(df['Period']),color='purple', label = 'Calendar Year Start / End',linewidth = 2, zorder = 1)   # put vertical line at Day 0 of calendar year
ax.vlines(365,-1,len(df['Period']),color='purple', linewidth = 2, zorder = 1) # put vertical line at Day 365 of calendar year


##
#   Draw horizontal line(s) to show the cycle for each period / row in dataframe.
##

for i in range(len(df)):

    ##  Option 1: Draw line between start and end points if start and end dates are in same calendar year (green marker to left of red).
    if df.loc[i]['Start'] < df.loc[i]['End']:
        ax.hlines(df.loc[i,'Period'], xmin=df.loc[i,'Start'], xmax=df.loc[i,'End'], color='blue', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0) 
         
    ##  Option 2: Draw 2 lines if the start or end dates are not in the same calendar year (red marker to left of green).
    else:
        ax.hlines(df.loc[i]['Period'], xmin=df.loc[i]['Start'], xmax=365, color='orange', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)  # end date is in next calendar year
        ax.hlines(df.loc[i]['Period'], xmin=0, xmax=df.loc[i]['End'], color='orange', linewidth = 2, zorder = 0)  # start date is in previous calendar year

ax.plot([],[],linewidth=2, label='Cycle', color='blue')  # just for legend only. 

ax.legend(ncol=2, loc = 'upper center')

## set the x axis to show the month names instead of day numbers
plt.xticks(np.linspace(0,365,13)[:-1], ('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov', 'Dec'))

plt.show()
```

Anybody know a better or more panda-esque method in lieu of the for loop and if-else statement?

Everyting I read says this is the 'worst' and slowest way to go through a dataframe, so this may be an issue when I apply it to hundreds of companies with hundreds of financial periods.